# Error in react native "`filePath` expects a string value"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, file-upload

I have some code to open the camera with React Native and save the image using FireBase, but it gives me an error saying `filePath` expects a string value.

[image]

Here is my code:

```js
 const openCamera = ()=>{
    launchCamera({quality:0.5},(fileobj) =>{
        console.log(fileobj)
        const uploadTask = storage().ref().child(`/items/${Date.now()}`).putFile(fileobj.uri)
        uploadTask.on('state_changed',
        (snapshot) => {
            var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
            if (progress == 100){alert("Uploaded")}
        },
        (error) => {
            alert("something went wrong")
        },
        () => {
            uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((downloadURL) =>{
                console.log(downloadURL)
                setImage(downloadURL)
            });
        }
        );
    })
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`launchCamera`](https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker#launchcamera) method accepts a callback that will be called with a response object. This [response object](https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker#the-response-object) has four keys; `didCancel`, `errorCode`, `errorMessage`, and `assets`.

[`assets`](https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker#Asset-Object) is an array of the selected media, so you'll need to grab the first one.

```js
const openCamera = () => {
  launchCamera({ quality: 0.5 }, (result) => {
    if (result.errorCode || result.didCancel) {
      return console.log('You should handle errors or user cancellation!');
    }
    const img = result.assets[0];
    const uploadTask = storage()
      .ref()
      .child(`/items/${Date.now()}`)
      .putFile(img.uri);

    uploadTask.on(
      'state_changed',
      (snapshot) => {
        var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
        if (progress == 100) {
          alert('Uploaded');
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        alert('something went wrong');
      },
      () => {
        uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((downloadURL) => {
          console.log(downloadURL);
          setImage(downloadURL);
        });
      },
    );
  });
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I saw your problem and I have a solution for you .
I don't know why but please try to use like this once :
`fileobj.assets[0].uri`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).